# Will a GTX 970 support a dual monitor setup using a Gsync panel on DisplayPort as the primary and a second panel on DVI?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I'm looking at upgrading my rig with this card:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NN0GEXQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NN0GEXQ)

Its a MSI GTX 970

I'd like to run a Gsync panel on the DisplayPort as a primary and then move my second panel to the DVI port. Will that setup work?

Comment: I just found this article that seems to address what I was researching. http://superuser.com/questions/316322/dvi-displayport-dual-monitors  It doesn't seem to have a solid answer though.

Comment: I have a friend which i believe uses gsync. I will ask him and post again.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says in this [FAQ](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/g-sync/faq)

```
Q: What graphics cards support NVIDIA G-SYNC technology?
A: Any GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST or higher GeForce GTX graphics card with 
a DisplayPort output is required.
```

Keep in mind that you another requirement is Windiws 7, 8 or 8.1

The second screen will work through DVI but of course without G-SYNC since it is only available through DisplayPort.

**EDIT:** I have asked someone who had a simliar setup running as you intent to. A GSYNC Asus Swift Screen (through DisplayPort) connected to a GTX Titan and a second Screen via DVI and it worked without problems. He assured me that this will work with any GPU from NVIDIA that supports GSYNC.

Comment: Thanks ap0. I think I got some bad info from a friend. He was telling me that using the DisplayPort disabled the DVI port.

Comment: I just posted a link to another article I found. I'm a bit uncertain again.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks much for the verification ap0.